# Any way to get a yield-style IEnumerable from this Win32 function?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

Consider the following contrived, minimal LINQPad example of implementing the Win32 function, [CertEnumSystemStoreLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certenumsystemstorelocation).  The concept extends to other methods in *crypt32.dll* but this is the simplest to demonstrate:

```
void Main()
{
    GetCertificateStoreLocations().Dump();
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetCertificateStoreLocations()
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    NativeMethods.CertEnumSystemStoreLocationCallback locationCallback = (location, flags, reserved, state) =>
    {
        var name = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(location);
        list.Add(name);
        return true;
    };

    if (!NativeMethods.CertEnumSystemStoreLocation(0u, IntPtr.Zero, locationCallback))
        throw new CryptographicException(Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error());

    return list.AsReadOnly();
}

private static class NativeMethods
{
    /// <seealso href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certenumsystemstorelocation"/>
    [DllImport("crypt32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool CertEnumSystemStoreLocation(uint reserved,
                                                          IntPtr stateObject,
                                                          CertEnumSystemStoreLocationCallback callback);

    /// <remarks>Implements PFN_CERT_ENUM_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCATION callback function</remarks>
    /// <seealso href="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nc-wincrypt-pfn_cert_enum_system_store_location"/>
    public delegate bool CertEnumSystemStoreLocationCallback(IntPtr storeLocation,
                                                             uint flags,
                                                             IntPtr reserved,
                                                             IntPtr stateObject);
}
```

The approach by this Win32 function is to enumerate over the certificate locations for you and run a user-supplied callback function for each object it finds.  It is semantically similar to the `static void ForEach(this IEnumerable<T>, Action<T>)` extension that I often see in tucked away in *Utils.cs* files across projects.

In my trivial implementation above, I use a lambda-based callback as a closure over a `List<string>` to collect values that are passed to my lambda by the Win32 function, and then return the entire list.  This satisfies my public method's `IEnumerable<string>` signature but isn't particularly *iterative*.

I am wondering if there is any reasonable C# approach to to do away with the whole `List<string>` creation/population/return, in favour of a proper iterator, for circumstances where the number of enumerated objects is not trivial.

A naive attempt might be to `yield return` from inside the lambda, instead of `list.Add` but, as far as I am aware, `yield return` cannot be used from inside a lambda.

I do note that the Win32 method takes a pointer to a state object, which is effectively a `struct` that you define, initialise and marshal, and the Win32 method will pass that through to your callback.  That *might* be usable, but that feels like it is setting me up for `IAsyncResult`-style programming and managing a `WaitHandle`, and I expect that using asynchronous programming to solve this particular problem is just going to give me two problems instead of one.

So I ask **is there a better way to structure the example code that might permit a more traditional iterative approach?**  i.e. one that more-closely satisfies `IEnumerable`/`yield return` semantics.

*(Note that I am not looking for an approach where I pass a `Func<T>`, `Action<T>` or delegate to a method that does the iteration – that would be the same as approach chosen by the crypt32.dll designers.)*

Comment: Yield caller wants to pulls one by one. API wants to push one by one. I don't see how you can reconcile those two, beyond building a complex multithreaded mailbox/queue system, which seems overkill in this case.

Comment: @SimonMourier; that's as far as I got, too, which I why I thought I'd open it up to the world, to see if I was missing anything...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that those kind of Win32 calls want to drive calls to the callback with their own loop internal to the call and an IEnumerator also wants a C# foreach loop or a LINQ loop to drive the flow of control via MoveNext() so any solution has to call the Win32 call in a separate thread -- as a kind of kluged coroutine. I see no way to avoid using two threads.

Below I wrap the Win32 call in a thread and implement the callback using two synchronization events, first waiting on an "someone is asking for the next value" event and then setting an "I just changed the string value" event. Then the MoveNext() method of the enumerator sets the first event and waits on the second. This seems to work but is generally more trouble than it is worth, in my opinion ... also you might need a lock around _current.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (string location in new CertEnumSystemStoreLocations())
            Console.WriteLine(location);
    }
}

public class CertEnumSystemStoreLocations : IEnumerable, IEnumerator<string>
{
    private EventWaitHandle _eventBeginMoveNext;
    private EventWaitHandle _eventEndMoveNext;
    private string _current;
    private Thread _thread;

    public CertEnumSystemStoreLocations()
    {
        _eventBeginMoveNext = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        _eventEndMoveNext = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CertEnumSystemStoreLocationThread));
        _thread.Start();
    }

    private void CertEnumSystemStoreLocationThread()
    {
        NativeMethods.CertEnumSystemStoreLocation(0, new IntPtr(), Callback);
        _eventBeginMoveNext.WaitOne();
        _current = null;
        _eventEndMoveNext.Set();
    }

    private bool Callback(IntPtr storeLocation, uint flags, IntPtr reserved, IntPtr stateObject)
    {
        _eventBeginMoveNext.WaitOne();
        _current = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(storeLocation);
        _eventEndMoveNext.Set();
        return true;
    }

    public string Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _current;
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        _eventBeginMoveNext.Set();
        _eventEndMoveNext.WaitOne();
        return _current != null;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        // TODO ... you'd need to tell the callback in the thread to
        // stop waiting on events etc. and then wait for the whole 
        // thread to run out ... 
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this;
    }
}

public static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("crypt32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool CertEnumSystemStoreLocation(uint reserved,
                                                          IntPtr stateObject,
                                                          CertEnumSystemStoreLocationCallback callback);

    public delegate bool CertEnumSystemStoreLocationCallback(IntPtr storeLocation,
                                                             uint flags,
                                                             IntPtr reserved,
                                                             IntPtr stateObject);
}
```